# How to decompress selected file from tar archive when file name contains some non-latin characters?

Tags: linux, unix, tar

I have a tar.bz2 archive, I want to decompress files with names containing special characters like for example `ë`

So I use:

```
tar -jxf "file.tar.bz2" -C "folder"
```

But it fails, error example:

`Can't create '211108_\235VRE TORVGATE 28_4112.ac'`

and the reason is `\235` which is unicode for `ë`

So... how can I decompress such files?

Thank you! :-)

Comment: Your command filters the output of the `tar` command which should be empty, it does not select the files to extract. Is this really the command you use?

Comment: Maybe https://superuser.com/a/504815/992527 if you have GNU tar.

Comment: BSD tar (installed as bsdtar by the libarchive-tools package on Debian/Ubuntu based distros) also supports wildcards.

Comment: @Bodo given regex finds files fine, the problem is with the file name in the archive, for example I get error:

Can't create '211108_\235VRE TORVGATE 28_4112.ac'

and the reason is \235 which unicode for ë

Answer (score 0):

When working with tar archives that contain file names with non-Latin characters, you may encounter issues with decompression. Here's how you can decompress a selected file from a tar archive with non-Latin file names:

1. Open a terminal window and navigate to the directory where the tar archive is located.
2. Use the tar tf command to list the contents of the tar archive, including the file names. For example, if your archive is named myarchive.tar, you can run the following command to list its contents:

```
tar tf myarchive.tar
```

This will display a list of all files and directories contained in the archive, including their file names.

3. Locate the file you want to extract and make a note of its full file name, including any non-Latin characters. For example, if the file name is 日本語.txt, make sure to copy the full name including the non-Latin characters.
4. Use the tar xf command to extract the selected file from the archive. For example, if you want to extract the file 日本語.txt, you can run the following command:

```
tar xf myarchive.tar 日本語.txt
```

This will extract the selected file from the archive and save it in the current directory.

If you encounter any issues with decompression, you may need to specify the character encoding used by the tar archive. You can do this by adding the --force-local and --no-anchored options to the tar command, followed by the appropriate character encoding. For example, if the archive uses the UTF-8 encoding, you can run the following command:

```
tar --force-local --no-anchored --charset=UTF-8 -xf myarchive.tar 日本語.txt
```

**This should allow you to decompress files with non-Latin file names from the tar archive.**

Comment: Can you explain in your answer why `--force-local` and `--no-anchored` are useful here? [Edit] the answer to do this.

Comment: @Kodexhub, this is what I get:

> tar -tf input_1682058644424.tar.bz2 | grep -E '^([^/]+).ac$'

> 211108_\235VRE TORVGATE 28_4112.ac

> tar -jxf "211108_\235VRE TORVGATE 28_4112.ac" -C "olo"

> tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '211108_\235VRE TORVGATE 28_4112.ac'

--force-local
--no-anchored
-- charset=UTF-8 

are not supported (I am using Mac machine)